# Flutter: can I find out what platform I am on?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am developping a project that should work both as an app and a web page. I am using flutter_secure_storage to store local data for the app, but I need a different approach for web.
Is there a way I can find out what platform I am on at runtime, and choose the correct read-write functions accordingly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can add this extension file to the project and call in any object

target.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

extension Target on Object {
  bool isAndroid() {
    return Platform.isAndroid;
  } 
  bool isIOS() {
    return Platform.isIOS;
  } 
  bool isLinux() {
  return Platform.isLinux;
  } 
  bool isWindows() {
  return Platform.isWindows; 
  }
  bool isMacOS() {
  return Platform.isMacOS; 
  }
  bool isWeb() {
  return kIsWeb; 
  }
  // ···
}
```

and import it anywhere and use it like this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isAndroid()? Text("Android"):Text("Not Android");
  }
```

Comment: I think it might be best if you just `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart` and then check `Platform.isXXX`.  I'm not sure what benefit extending `Object` gives, and this approach clutters up auto-completion for every `Object` derived type.

Answer (score 4):

for web, you use:

```
if(kIsWeb) //returns a boolean if your app is running in a browser.
```

For other platform, you use `Platform`

```
Platform.isAndroid
Platform.isIos
Platform.isLinux
```

Make sure to check that you are running on web first, before calling `Platform.is`, because it'll throw an exception that platform is not available for this environment.

Answer (score 2):

How to detect what platform a Flutter app is running on:
Flutter provides two different APIs that enables the caller to get to know more about the current platform: the kIsWeb constant that is part of the foundation library and the Platform class being part of the platform library.
Link to code:
https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/how-to-detect-what-platform-a-flutter-app-is-running-on/2020/127/

```
 import 'dart:io';
 import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
 class PlatformInfo {
 bool isDesktopOS() {
  return Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isLinux || Platform.isWindows;
 }
 bool isAppOS() {
 return Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isAndroid;
  }
 bool isWeb() {
 return kIsWeb;
}
 PlatformType getCurrentPlatformType() {
  if (kIsWeb) {
     return PlatformType.Web;
}
  if (Platform.isMacOS) {
  return PlatformType.MacOS;
}
  if (Platform.isFuchsia) {
  return PlatformType.Fuchsia;
}
if (Platform.isLinux) {
  return PlatformType.Linux;
}
if (Platform.isWindows) {
  return PlatformType.Windows;
}
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  return PlatformType.iOS;
}
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  return PlatformType.Android;
}
return PlatformType.Unknown;
}
}
enum PlatformType {
 Web,
 iOS,
 Android,
 MacOS,
 Fuchsia,
 Linux,
 Windows,
 Unknown
 }
```

This gives an easy possiblity to make decisions based on the OS or the group of underlying platforms:

```
Text _getMicrophoneSection() {
 if (PlatformInfo.isAppOS()) {
  return Text('Please tap the microphone button and then permit the              usage');
  }
 return Text('If you have a microphone available, please turn it on');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect if Flutter is compiled for web you may use kIsWeb from package
`import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'`. For other environments like Android, IOS, Windows, Mac you may use [Platform class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-platform_platform/Platform-class.html) like

`Platform.IsWindows`